# Has it been proved that odd perfect numbers cannot be triangular?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, divisors-multiples, perfect-numbers

(Note:  This question has been cross-posted from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1711177).)

Euclid and Euler proved that every even perfect number is of the form $m = \frac{{M_p}\left(M_p + 1\right)}{2}$ where $M_p = 2^p - 1$ is a prime number, called a *Mersenne prime*.  Thus, an even perfect number is [triangular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

On the other hand, Euler showed that an odd perfect number, if one exists, takes the form $N = q^k n^2$, where $q$ is prime with $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n) = 1$.  (Descartes, Frenicle and subsequently Sorli conjectured that $k = 1$ always holds.)

Here is my question:

> **Has it been proved that odd perfect numbers cannot be triangular?**

**Added March 26 2016**

If $\sigma(q) = 2n^2$, then it would follow that $n < q$, which implies that $k = 1$.  The odd perfect number $N = q^k n^2$ then takes the form $N = \frac{q(q + 1)}{2}$.  Unfortunately, it is known that $\sigma(q^k) \leq \frac{2n^2}{3}$.

Any pointers to the existing literature containing such a proof would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

Curiously enough, I asked myself the same question several days ago... I couldn't settle it; yet, resorting to [Jacques Touchard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Touchard)'s theorem on the form of odd perfect numbers (cf. J. A. Holdener, "A theorem of Touchard on the form of odd perfect numbers". *Amer. Math. Monthly*, **109** (2002), no. 7, pp. 661-663), one can easily establish the following result:

**Proposition.** If $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is and odd perfect number, then $n \equiv 1 \pmod{24}$ or $n \equiv 9 \pmod{72}$ or $n \equiv 17 \pmod{72}$.

Comment: +1, this answer adds perspective to the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but I just want to point out some thoughts that recently occurred to me, which are related to this problem.

By this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2112125/28816), we know that every odd perfect number $N = q^k n^2$ can be written in the form
$$N = \dfrac{q(q+1)}{2} \cdot d$$
where $d > 1$.  (That is, an odd perfect number is a nontrivial multiple of the triangular number
$$T(q) = \dfrac{q(q+1)}{2},$$
where $q$ is the *Euler prime* of $N$.)

If $k=1$, then it is easy to show that
$$d = D(n^2)$$
where $D(n^2) = 2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)$ is the [*deficiency*](http://oeis.org/A033879) of the non-Euler part $n^2$.

(I have asked a separate question for the form of $d'$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2112136), if $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with $k > 1$, and $N = \dfrac{q(q+1)}{2} \cdot d'$ with $d' > 1$.)